# Comparing stored procedure execution plan at different queries

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, database-performance, sql-server-2016, sql-execution-plan

When I compare execution plans of stored procedures, it only does the first one.  I want to compare query 3 which is the main SP but I just am not able to.  Is there a way to do this in SQL Server where I can see the stats on the right Properties window.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean "compare query 3"?   compare it to what?

Comment: Look in the screenshot bud

Comment: What happens if you click the down arrow next to "USE DATABASE" at the top of the right pane?

Comment: Nothing, empty.

Comment: This makes it look like you can somehow highlight the areas you want to focus on in the right pane.   I don't have 2016 yet, so I can't verify:   https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_server_team/comparison-tool-released-with-latest-ssms/

Comment: I believe this works the same in previous versions.  Those screenshots in those articles are a single SP, but single query.  When I highlight something it does not change the right side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 'Multi Statement' tab under 'Showplan Compare Options' that allows you to choose which queries you want to compare:
[image]

I'm not sure why it's not shown in the picture you've uploaded.

Comment: How in the world did I miss that!

Comment: I actually dont have that option on another computer

Comment: Looks like an older version of SQL Server 2016 doesnt have that option

Comment: The version I am using is 13.0.16105.4

Comment: Yep the one that doesnt have it is 13.0.15900.1 but the one that works has 13.0.16106.4.